# My javascript calculator doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a web calculator utilizing values of text input as numbers and replacing a label at the bottom with the result. Although the problem I am facing is that the functions are either not being called or some other stuff. I am just starting out on Javascript, if you guys would point the problem out, I'll be much grateful.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Calc+</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="calculator.css">
</head>
<body>


<header>
<div class="container"><center><p><strong>Tarun's</strong>|Calculator</p>
</center></div> 
</header>
<section id="calculator">
<div class="container">
    <table id="inputs"><tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="firstnumber"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="secondnumber"></td>
       </tr>
</table>
<table id="operators" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="7">
    <tr>
        <td id="plus"><button onClick="addition()">+</button></td>
        <td id="minus"><button onClick="difference()">-</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td id="multiply"><button onClick="multiplication()">*</button></td>
        <td id="divide"><button onClick="division()">/</button></td></tr>   
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><center><label id="result">result</label></center></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>


function additon()
{
var a = document.getElementById('firstnumber').value;
var b = document.getElementById('secondnumber').value;
document.getElementById("result") = a + b;
}
function difference()
{
var a = document.getElementById('firstnumber').value;
var b = document.getElementById('secondnumber').value;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = a - b;

}
function multiplication()
{
var a = document.getElementById('firstnumber').value;
var b = document.getElementById('secondnumber').value;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = a * b;

}
function division()
{
var a = document.getElementById('firstnumber').value;
var b = document.getElementById('secondnumber').value;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = a / b;

}
```

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: What have you tried so far? We can't help you if we can't see your code.

Comment: All we know is that your calculator doesn't work, but we can't fix what we can't see

Comment: Sorry for being dumb, didn't even put the code there.

Comment: please edit your post and detail how to reproduce an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four major problems with your code.

First the whole JavaScript code (starting with "function addition()") is not inside a script tag. Currently it just gets interpreted as text, thats the reason why you should see it at the bottom when you load your side. To fix this you have to embed the code inside a script tag. The easiest way to do this is inside the head tag as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Calc+</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="calculator.css">
<script>
    function additon()
    //other functions here
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

Second the addition function does not set the innerHTML. Just set the innerHTML there like you did with the other functions.

Third, if you get the value as you try it, the type is actually a string. If you do string + string, the result is a concatination. So "1" + "1" = "11". To change this, just add a + before the a in the addition case, as follows
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = +a + b;
(Thanks to Frederik Hansen who pointed that one out in the comments.)

Fourth, the addition function isn't named correctly. You wrote additon but you meant addition.

Comment: Also, the value being returned is a string. Adding two strings in JavaScript concatenates them. To fix this, cast one of the numbers to a number like so: `var result = +a + b;`

Comment: Kudos to you. Owe you a coffee.

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to make this calculator following the input and label replace constraints?